# Simple deeplearning4J Java based Spark example?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, deeplearning4j

I need to run a simple Java based deeplearning4j example in hadoop cluster and I found one [here](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java). My need to specify the input from command line (which should be a path on HDFS) and output should go to HDFS, for later view

However, in the example there is no mention, it is hard coding the input from local file system and output goes to local file system.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some combination of this recent pull request on our examples:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/pull/384

and Spring-hadoop could help you?
http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/

I mean conceptually all you'd do is change the file system type.

The FileSystem api in hadoop can point to either local or an hdfs url so there shouldn't be much change.